# CMake Difference between include_directories and add_subdirectory?

Tags: c++, cmake, thrift

I'm learning CMake for building C++ code, and struggling with the following concept.  On my root level directory I have some cpp files and a CMakeLists.txt that succesfully generates some thrift code in a gen-cpp directory.  My root level CMakeLists.txt contains :

include_directories("path-to-root"/gen-cpp).    (along with the relevant thrift auto-generating and includes.

Everything compiles ok but I get run time dynamic library linked errors for undefined symbol referencing a class defined in the gen-cpp directory.  When I move the files in the directory to the root level, it runs fine.  what am I missing?  (I had also adjusted the #include in the root level cpp directorie s to point to "path-to-root"/gen-cpp).

Is this a misunderstanding of using include_directory, where I should be using add_subdirectory.  If the latter, would the code in gen-cpp needs its own CMakeLists.txt?  Why is this additional file not needed, when the contents of said directory are root level?

Answer (score 23):

`add_subdirectory(source_dir)`: Used to add a subdirectory to the build. There is also a CMakeLists.txt file in the source_dir. This CMakeLists.txt file in the specified source directory will be processed immediately by CMake before processing in the current input file continues beyond this command.

`include_directories(dir)`: Add the given directories to those the compiler uses to search for include files. These directories are added to the directory property INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES for the current CMakeLists file.

Answer (score 15):

The `include_directories()` is used for adding headers search paths (`-I` flag) and `add_subdirectory()` will make no difference in this case.

I suppose, you need to list *.cpp files from gen-cpp folder in `add_executable()` or `add_library()` calls, in which you wish these symbols to be.

Alternatively, you can compile all thrift sources into the library and link it with your code.

Comment: To elaborate on your last point, that sounds like would be the ideal way to deal with this,  is there an example of using a CMake macro used to auto-generate/compile/link thrift code that someone can point me to?

Comment: I think I'm still not quite explaining my problem correctly, I believe it lies in my general understanding of Cmake, not specifically to thrift.  The generic problem is given a top level directory structure that contains a CMakeLists.txt,  some .cpp/.h files, and a directory that contains additional .cpp/.h files that those in the top level directory #include---  which commands should I be looking at in the root level CMakeLists.txt to properly compile/link the files in the inner directory?    Would I also need an additional CMakeLists.txt in the inner directory, if so containing what?

Comment: Nope, you don't need it. Just list these files in add_*() call: `add_executable(myexe file1.cpp folder/file2.cpp)`.

Comment: In which case include_directories is as same as add_subdirectory, in which case is difference. if some one could please have an example.