# cmake: add_subdirectory() vs include()

Tags: cmake

Let's say I have a C++ unit-test project using cmake like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── C-API-ConditionVariable-unit-test
│   ├── C-API-ConditionVariable-compile-link-test.c
│   ├── C-API-ConditionVariable-unit-test-0.cpp
│   └── C-API-ConditionVariable-unit-test-1.cpp
├── C-API-Mutex-unit-test
│   ├── C-API-Mutex-compile-link-test.c
│   ├── C-API-Mutex-unit-test-0.cpp
│   └── C-API-Mutex-unit-test-1.cpp
├── some
│   └── deeply
│       └── nested
│           └── path
│               └── SomeFeature-unit-test
│                   ├── SomeFeature-compile-link-test.c
│                   ├── SomeFeature-unit-test-0.cpp
│                   └── SomeFeature-unit-test-1.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

Each source file from the subfolders creates a separate executable. I would like to have each subfolder in the project to be a non-standalone module - that is each subfolder is (more-or-less) self-contained, but is NOT a standalone cmake project which can be compiled separately. I would like to be able to only build everything or nothing. For example I don't want to make an impression that you could run cmake only from `some/deeply/nested/path/SomeFeature-unit-test` to build only that.

Which option should I choose?

1. `CMakeLists.txt` file in each subfolder + `add_subdirectory()` in top-level `CmakeLists.txt`;
2. `some-random-name.cmake` in each subfolder + `include()` in top-level `CmakeLists.txt`;
3. ignore my idea for each subfolder to be self-contained and put all relevant build info in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, additional cmake files only as helpers (macros, functions, ...);

The first option is the most convenient, but it suggests that each subfolder is actually a standalone project which could be compiled separately.

The second option seems to clearly suggest that there is only one cmake project here. But then in each `some-random-name.cmake` in subfolders I have to use full path to source files, which is against my desire for each of them to be self contained. If there's only one level of nesting (like for first two example subfolders) it is ok, but for `some/deeply/nested/path/SomeFeature-unit-test` this is not so nice. I would also have to prefix the names of output files.

The third option seems like an easy way to quickly create a `CMakeLists.txt` file with a length of a spaghetti, so it possible I would prefer something else.

I would like know which is the "preferred" way in a "modern" cmake project. All the tutorials I could find for multi-directory project deal with the case when there's a standalone library in one folder, standalone application using that library in another folder and standalone tests using the same library in yet another directory. Looking at projects using cmake I see no consistency, so this doesn't help much.

(I'm a cmake noob, trying to convert a relatively large project to use cmake)

Comment: `I would like know which is the "preferred" way in a "modern" cmake project.` - There is no single "preferred" way. Choose the one which seems to be convenient to you, and implement it. BTW, the way with `add_subdirectory` by itself doesn't implies subproject to be standalone.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - as a complete cmake noob I would prefer to base my choices on some kind of common knowledge instead of my own preferences (; You say that my understanding that `CMakeLists.txt` implies the folder to be standalone is wrong? But then if a particular repository would contain a few cmake projects, how can you tell which `CMakeLists.txt` should you use to build something without reading the documentation?

Comment: "But then if a particular repository would contain a few cmake projects, how can you tell which CMakeLists.txt should you use to build something without reading the documentation?" - No way. On may **guess** that top-level `CMakeLists.txt` will be the needed one. But it could be that required `CMakeLists.txt` is in the *some other* project; e.g. in the case when given project provides a plugin.

Answer (score 75):

The most commonly used rule is "One `CMakeLists.txt` per target". So your option No. 1.

To achieve this your project structure may have to adapt, if "each source file from the subfolders creates a separate executable".

And the root `CMakeLists.txt` is your starting point and contains the `project()` command.

It's important to note that

- CMake will mirror your `add_subdirectory()` and `CMakeLists.txt` directory structure in its generated build environment
- CMake will create a new variable scope with each `add_subdirectory()` call ([the big difference to using `include()` command](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-November/017897.html))

What you should avoid is having to reference source files out of other subdirectories with something like `../some_other_dir/some_other_source.cpp`. It shows that your CMake structure is not setup according to the rule of thumb quoted above.

**Documentation Extracts**

1. [CMake: `add_subdirectory()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html)

   > Add a subdirectory to the build. The `source_dir` specifies the directory in which the source `CMakeLists.txt` and code files are located.
2. [CLion: CMakeLists File](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmakelists-file.html)

   > When a project has the complex structure and includes one or more subdirectories (project root and subdirectories), you can create subdirectory `CMakeList.txt` files. Subdirectory `CMakeLists.txt` files describe the build, contents, and target rules for a subdirectory.
3. [C++Now 2017: Daniel Pfeifer "Effective CMake: a random selection of best practices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk)

   > Directories that contain a `CMakeLists.txt` are the entry point for the build system generator. Subdirectories may be added with `add_subdirectory()` and must contain a `CMakeLists.txt` too.

**References**

- [Embracing Modern CMake](https://steveire.wordpress.com/2017/11/05/embracing-modern-cmake/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186110/cmake-tutorial
- [CMake with subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744315/cmake-with-subdirectories)
- [CMake share library with multiple executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443164/cmake-share-library-with-multiple-executables)
- [Renaming `CMakeLists.txt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309734/renaming-cmakelists-txt)

Comment: Thank you Florian. This is a fantastic answer. I wish I had've found this before reading everything else.

Comment: The second reference: "CMake tutorial" is broken

Comment: possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761748/cmake-difference-between-include-directories-and-add-subdirectory

Comment: Beautiful answer! Helps a lot!